# Unable to understand cv2.bitwise_and()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have had a look at the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.2/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=bitwise#bitwise-and). However I am still not able to understand this function completely.

In particluar,

```
dest = cv2.bitwise_and(a,a,mask=b)
```

What does this mean? Here b is also an image of same dimensions.

From the documentation, when `b[i]!=0` then `dest[i] = a[i]^a[i]`.
What if `b[i] == 0`?

Comment: http://onegoodmove.org/fallacy/images/and.gif Replace T with 1 and F with 0

Comment: So are we doing `a and a and  b`?

Comment: @DeepSpace [a](http://imgur.com/2FDZJRu), [mask](http://imgur.com/E3MUQrA), [dest](http://imgur.com/m4Mn24M). Here it not working like you mention, if I understood what you said

Comment: I think it's more like `(a & a) && b` where b is "and"ed logically instead of binary.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler Can you explain how this works for the links posted in the above comment?

Comment: for the pixels where `mask[i]!=0` it writes the result of bitwise and of `src1[i]` and `src2[i]`. for the pixels where `mask[i]==0` it doesn't change the destination matrix. It leaves the pixels black( or whatever color you initialized the matrix with).

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler I didn't initialise the matrix

Comment: I checked the source code in OpenCv and found that it clears the destination matrix (all pixels to `0.0`).  Source code: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp (line:253)

Comment: It means that `dest` will contain values from `a` in places where `b` is non-zero, and zeros everywhere else. The first part is due to `a AND a == a`. The second part is due to a new `dest` array being allocated, since you didn't provide one of appropriate size and type as a parameter -- the newly allocated array is filled with zeros.